# How to prevent spam in docblock comments?

Tags: php, email, comments, spam, docblocks

I often publish PHP code on GitHub and in my code I use docblock comments that contain, among other things, my email address like this:

```
/**
 * @author Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>
 */
```

I fear that this is going to attract spammers and I am looking for a way to prevent this. Is there a good way to do this?

I have seen that some open-source projects use this format: example.com:foo.bar. Is this enough to trick spammers?

Regards,

Comment: I wrote an email collector once, If it's there, They can find it (unless you use a method that's unique to you! )

Comment: Could you use your GitHub URL instead of an e-mail address?